# Curatorframework checkexists() function, causing problems when overloaded, or add to zookeeper in high rate

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I use the following to add node in zookeeper:

```
public void put(String key, String value) throws Exception {
String fullPath = calculateFullPath(key);
preparePath(fullPath). forPath(fullPath, value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF-8));
}

private PathAndBytesable preparePath(String fullPath) throws Exception {
return checkIfFullPathExists(fullPath) ? client.setData() : client.create().creatingParentsIfNeeded();
}

private boolean checkIfFullPathExists(String fullPath) throws Exception {
ExistsBuilder existsBuilder = client.checkExists();
return existsBuilder.forPath(fullPath) != null;
}
```

But when I add nodes in a high rate , the put function start to take time, more and more, when I checked what can cause the problem,  I saw that that the checkexists() was the Bottleneck,
Any idea
What can I use instead ?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think that it's quite clear

Comment: Why do you check if the path exists? That seems wasteful and will definitely take time.

Comment: Well, I checked if I can simply put the value on an already existing node, and it threw NodeExistsException unfortunately. Therefore I always needed to validate the path already exists before I put a new node or an existing node. Is there any other way you think I can achieve the same target? I will be really grateful!